# Kendo directive not working

Tags: html, angularjs, kendo-ui

This is my controller part where I am initialzaing kendo directive. I have a single page app.

```
var app = angular.module("amazonfresh", ["ngRoute","kendo.directives"]);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/index", {
    templateUrl: "partials/login.html",
    controller: "AuthController"
}).when("/customers/signup", {
    templateUrl: "partials/customers/signup.html",
    controller: "CustomersController"
}).otherwise({redirectTo: "/index"});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){

});
```

HTML content. I want the personal,general,credit card information to be shown as tabstrip using kendo but here it displays as bullets.

```
<div class="demo-section k-content">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <div kendo-tab-strip k-content-urls="[ null, null]">
                <ul>
                    <li class="k-state-active">Personal Information</li>
                    <li>Genreal Information</li>
                    <li>Credit Card Information</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

//Main index.html file. This has a div tag with ng-view directive. When I launch the application kendo directives does not work. Can someone help me out. I am new to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<!--Scripts-->
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/angular-1.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for authentication-->
<script src="/javascripts/services/AuthService.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/AuthController.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts for customers -->
<script src="/javascripts/controllers/customersController.js"></script>

<!-- Other scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--<script data-main="/javascripts/main.js" src="/javascripts/vendor/require-2.2.0.js"></script>-->

<!-- Stylesheets -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/smallicons-logotypes/32/amazon-16.png"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.412/js/kendo.all.min.js">  </script>
<base href="/">
```

```
<body ng-app="amazonfresh">
<div id="nav">
<div class="innerpadding">
        <li id="logo"><a href="#">
            <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/omaha/images/ui/af-logo-white-trans3.png"
                 alt="AmazonFresh Home"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main-content" ng-view>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise by "kendo directives does not work" ? First check your javscript includes, you include twice angular and jquery. And i think you forgot to provide a default route (routerProvider.otherwise)

Comment: i have provided routerProvider.otherwise. What i meant is properties are not getting applied to my html as i want a tabstrip using kendo